# Timestamp in python like Facebook

Tags: python, datetime

How can I get the custom string of timestamp just like Facebook or any other social media platform example is given below:

```
foo commented 1h ago
```

I want this similar functionality in my application can anyone help me out with this, I have two DateTime objects one is the timestamp for comment and another one is the current DateTime object.

```
    def get_timestamp(self):
        """
        Returns the timestamp with formatting

        @Returns:
            - timestamp (str): thr string of timestamp
        """
        time = timezone.now()
        if self.timestamp.minute == time.minute:
            sec_change = time.second - self.timestamp.second
            if sec_change == 0:
                return "Just now"
            return str(sec_change) + "s"
        elif self.timestamp.hour == time.hour:
            return str(time.minute - self.timestamp.minute) + "min"
        elif self.timestamp.day == time.day:
            return str(time.hour - self.timestamp.hour) + "h"
        elif self.timestamp.month == time.month:
            return str(time.day - self.timestamp.day) + "d"
        elif self.timestamp.year == time.year:
            return str(time.month - self.timestamp.month) + "y"
        ....
```

currently, I have created a function for this functionality but this has some logical errors I think, because this will only work when `day==day`, `month==month`, `year==year` but think when we comment at the end of the day it directly shows 1d ago that's not the case. This also seems that code is not good because it takes so many lines for a simple logic.

Comment: seems like you'd be better of if you'd derive the message from a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)?

Comment: yeah it seems that this would be a great solution let me implement it on my side